# Oracle Foreign Key Issues with Multi-Table Inserts and Blobs

Tags: oracle, insert, foreign-keys, blob, multi-table

We have a single table that we want to break up into a tree of tables based upon a particular source column. I wanted to try using a multi-column insert, but it seems that if I insert a blob into a sub table, I wind up with a foreign key constraint violation.

I don't think this violates the [rules about multi-table inserts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2095116) but I could be wrong...

I am hoping that someone could point me to some more in-depth resources around what is actually going on here, so that I can feel confident that whatever solution will work as part of a liquibase changeset on Oracle databases 9i -> 11g.

## Hopefully Simplified Scenario

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    pk NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO source (pk,type,content) values (1,'two','n/a');
INSERT INTO source (pk,type,content) values (2,'one','Content');

CREATE TABLE dest (
    pk NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE dest_one  (
    pkfk NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_ONE FOREIGN KEY (pkfk) REFERENCES dest (pk)
);


CREATE TABLE dest_two  (
    pkfk NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_TWO FOREIGN KEY (pkfk) REFERENCES dest (pk)
 );
```

Source contains our original data. dest will be our parent table, with children dest_one and dest_two (which will contain information on things of type 'one' or 'two' respectively). Things of type one have content, but things of type two do not.

### The Failed Attempt

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN 1=1 THEN INTO dest (pk,type) VALUES (pk,type)
WHEN type='one' THEN INTO dest_one (pkfk,data) VALUES (pk,content)
WHEN type='two' THEN INTO dest_two (pkfk) VALUES (pk)
SELECT pk,type,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(content) as content from source where type in ('one','two');
```

As previously mentioned, I wound up with a foreign key constraint violation here. To further illustrate that the blob was the issue I tried two seperate similar queries (below) realizing the one without the blob insert worked, but with the blob insert failed.

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN 1=1 THEN INTO dest (pk,type) VALUES (pk,type)
WHEN type='two' THEN INTO dest_two (pkfk) VALUES (pk)
SELECT pk,type,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(content) as content from source where type = 'two';
/* Successful */

INSERT ALL
WHEN 1=1 THEN INTO dest (pk,type) VALUES (pk,type)
WHEN type='one' THEN INTO dest_one (pkfk,data) VALUES (pk,content)
SELECT pk,type,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(content) as content from source where type = 'one';
/* ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated, no parent key */
```

### Solution 1 - Traditional Inserts

```
INSERT INTO dest (pk,type) SELECT pk,type from source where type in ('one','two');
INSERT INTO dest_two (pkfk) SELECT pk from source where type = 'two';
INSERT INTO dest_one (pkfk,data) SELECT pk,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(content) from source where type = 'one';
```

One option I am considering is going back to multiple seperate insert statements, but unlike how I have stated them here, I'm concerned that I'll have to make sure I write my sub-table inserts to only attempt to insert those rows present in parent dest table... I need to do more research on how Liquibase handles multiple sql statements in the same changeset.

### Solution 2 - Temporarily disabling foreign key constraints

```
ALTER TABLE dest_one DISABLE CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_ONE;
```

INSERT ALL
WHEN 1=1 THEN INTO dest (pk,type) VALUES (pk,type)
WHEN type='one' THEN INTO dest_one (pkfk,data) VALUES (pk,content)
WHEN type='two' THEN INTO dest_two (pkfk) VALUES (pk)
SELECT pk,type,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(content) as content from source where type in ('one','two');

ALTER TABLE dest_one ENABLE CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_ONE;

This is the solution I'm leaning toward. While disabling the foreign key on my blob table seems to make it work in my test environment (10g - 10.2.0.1.0), I'm not sure if I should also be disabling the foreign key on the non-blob table as well (due to how 9i, 11g, or other versions of 10g may behave). Any resources here too would be appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to defer the constraint evaluation until COMMIT.  I suspect (but am not sure) that the multi-table insert is inserting rows in an order other than the one you expect and want.  Recreate your constraints as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE DEST_ONE DROP CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_ONE;

ALTER TABLE DEST_ONE
  ADD CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_ONE
    FOREIGN KEY (pkfk) REFERENCES dest (pk) 
    INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE DEST_TWO DROP CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_TWO;

ALTER TABLE DEST_TWO
  ADD CONSTRAINT XFK1DEST_TWO
    FOREIGN KEY (pkfk) REFERENCES dest (pk)
    INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
```

This re-creates the constraints so that they can be deferred, and are deferred from the time they're created.  Then try your original INSERT again.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Nice! To be honest I didn't know about that before, but that's really neat, and Liquibase supports it when declaring foreign keys as well.

Comment: I'm still curious though if someone would happen to know more, why would blob seem to throw off the insertion order here...